# Any DynDNS client for current iOS for usage with nsupdate.info?

Tags: ios, script, dns

This is my first question here and my first experience with iOS. As a long-time Windows and Linux user, I have been asked to install a client (updater) for the dynamic DNS service nsupdate.info on a phone with iOS (current version).

I have researched the situation and came across RealDNS and some others, but none of them seems to be intended to work with nsupdate.info.

On Windows, it is the same, but I solved the problem there just by writing a script which performs the updates and which is triggered by the task scheduler on a regular basis.

But unfortunately, I don't have Apple's development tools, and I have no clue whether I could run a script on iOS at all, so I can't develop something myself. Plus, I have no knowledge of how to develop software for iOS (including scripts).

Could somebody help me out there? As a last resort, I could look into the list of providers RealDNS supports, and use one of these services. However, I'd like to know of other options (if any) before I do this.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what to you need the current IP of an iPhone for? There are no services running on it which could be accessed from „outside“.

Comment: It is for a IPSec-based / IKEv2 VPN. When the phone establishes the VPN, it presents a certificate to the remote gateway. The certificate has the phone's FQDN in its DN and also in its subjectAltName. The remote gateway reads these fields, resolves the subjectAltName to an IP address, and checks whether that resulting IP address is the same as the IP address of the client which tries to dial in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nsupdate.info should work with any dyndns2-compatible client

> You usually need it so your router (or other dyndns2-compatible client) can update a hostname, so you don't need to know or find out your current IP address

You also can do quite a lot of scripting with the Shortcuts app (https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios) which is part of iOS (you may need to download it from the Store in case you removed it in the past). There are actions to call any URL and to process JSON results.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and +1. Could you please give me a tip which DynDNS client for iOS speaks dyndns2 *and* lets you freely enter the provider? I am aware that most of the DynDNS services provide dyndns2 APIs, so in theory you could use any of those clients to update names with nsupdate.info. However, in all iOS clients I found, you can only choose from a list of providers; that is, you can't freely input a provider. nsupdate.info was not in the provider list of any client I saw ... I hope this is not too embarrassing :-)

Comment: @binarus I only had a quick look into the store and didn‘t find any. Maybe some of them (RealDNS) might be willing to extend their list or provide an expert mode?

Comment: Thank you very much again. I am surprised that this is so difficult. I'll now recommend to use RealDNS and to create a new hostname with one of the providers RealDNS supports. That also means that I have to create new certificates, but this is not too much work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://www.dynu.com/DynamicDNS/IPUpdateClient/iOS
so far s the only one I found. The good thing is it is made by an actual DynDNS provider with a free option.